# Rearranging a class's methods, properties and variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008, is it possible to rearrange a C# file automatically based on methods, properties or variables?

I could do this by manually, but was wondering if there is something that will automatically do the arranging. Basically I would like some kind of a grouping mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

Not natively.  Have a look at [**ReSharper**](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) by JetBrains.  It's not free, but more than pays for itself in a little over 5 minutes of usage (depending on how slow you type).

**EDIT:**
In response to comments, I must qualify that reordering and group code blocks in ReSharper requires the StyleCop for ReSharper plugin.  It is a free, open source plugin for ReSharper and is [**available on Codeplex**](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Re-sharper doesn't provide this functionality.

Comment: @squillman, please point me to the actual resharper function because I've got resharper and I wouldn't have installed regionerate if it did (or rather if I could find the function). I'm running the latest version of R# in VS2010.

Comment: @BenCr Sorry, you're right.  I do need to qualify my answer because there is a plugin required.  See my edit.

Comment: @squillman, I'm still fairly confident that it doesn't do what he's asked for. It will arrange static before non static, private before public and readonly before not readonly but I don't think it'll rearrange all fields to the top, then constructor, then properties and then methods. p.s. someone I work with worked on the Style Cop for R# plug-in so we use that as well :)

Comment: @BenCr Oh it definitely does, I use it all the time.

Comment: Great, i'd like to use it as well. Where do I run it from?

Comment: @BenCr Install R#, Install StyleCop, then install the StyleCop for R# plugin.  The plugin integrates StyleCop rules into R# code inspection.  You configure how R# uses the StyleCop rules through R# options.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me how to re-arrange a source file so that it's fields first, then constructor, properties and then methods. It'll highlight the errors where the members are in the wrong order, but it can't fix them, you have to manually move the code elements.

Comment: @BenCr There are StyleCop code formatting rules that will automatically do the moving when code cleanup is performed on a source file.  R#'s code cleanup function uses the code inspection rules.  Also, if you use R#'s auto code inserting it'll follow the StyleCop rules as well.

Comment: Okay then, so to answer my earlier question, to re-arrange a source file, run Code Clean-up. I'll try this on Monday. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @BenCr Yep, you got it.  Make sure you install everything, and then double check the style cop rules in the Code Inspections options of R#.

Comment: @squillman, and as you obviously knew, you're correct. Thanks for that, I'll remove that awful Regionerate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free plugin called Regionerate. I personally don't like it but it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at CodeRush Xpress for C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee663901.aspx it is free and has refactoring tools included.

Answer (score 0):

Or by chance if you are using "DevExpress" in your projects, it comes with Refactoring utility which you can make use of.